# Spark Accumulator reporting Incorrect count while parsing Json file using Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am trying to process json Array formatted files using Spark. Below is the code I'm using to parse the json file in Spark using RDD and count the number of records in the file using an accumulator.

```
val baseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[Array[Byte], Array[Byte], JFormat](params.inputRootPath)
        baseRDD.foreachPartition(partition => {
          partition.foreach(tranSeqID_rawBytes => {
            totRecParsed.add(1)
            val trans = new xyz(tranSeqID_rawBytes._2, "test")
          })
        })
        baseRDD
```

This is reader logic in the JFormat class used while creating the RDD

```
public JsonWrapper(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    reader.beginArray();
  }

  public String getNextRecord() throws IOException {
    if (reader.hasNext()) {
      JsonObject str = new Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
      return str.toString();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The accumulator reports 2x to 10x counts while parsing the json array file this way. Strange part is this is not the case when the file sizes / counts are low . This count mismatch is seen when processing large files. Is there anything I'm missing?

I do not see any failed tasks while processing the file and one thing i observed is the total records parsed on each executor is same as the records present in the file I am trying to process i.e. 1609132. Does it mean that all the executors are processing the entire file?  [image: Executor wise accumulator counts]